# Adding meaningful text to integer codes

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-form

I have a lot of attributes being coded as integers like 0 meaning 'No', 1 meaning 'Perhaps', 2 meaning 'Yes' etc. I would like to show the text instead in an attribute table in a layout.

With just one attribute I would add a file with the numbers and the associated text and join this on the attribute. But I can only join a file to one attribute so I will have to duplicate the file for every attribute.

There must be an easier/smarter way to do this?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think there is a smarter way ;-)

Consider a layer like this:

[image]

(`0,1,2` is stored value) ...you can set up the attributes widget in the attribute forms properties of your layer to "Value Map" like this (or load them from a file as well):

[image]

Then in the attribute table you will have the descriptions displayed:

[image]

Note that still the integers are stored, the attribute form now looks like this:

[image]

The approach works in print layouts also:

[image]

You may even export the descriptions/displayed values like this (e.g. Excel):

[image]

...results in:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Virtual Layer. Then use this to view the data in QGIS, or export it to file.

I have one point table named **building** with code columns, and join two other tables **types** and **colors** which have the codes and corresponding descriptions as text,

```sql
SELECT a.*, b.typetext, colortext
FROM building a
LEFT JOIN types b
ON a.typecode=b.typecode
LEFT JOIN colors c
ON a.colorcode = c.colorcode
--keep joining all your tables
```

[image]